# Simple C program, some questions about functions

Tags: c, function, sum

I'm a beginner with programming in C and I have a problem to solve at which point I get stuck.

So my program reads numbers until the value 0 then it calculates the sum of numbers. Then I have to write a function which displays the sum. Also, my program read a number "y" from keyboard and I need to find the result of the sum/y.For example if the result of the sum is 10 and I enter y=3 the function result should return the result of 10/3.

My program need to be built with functions. I received the functions name with parameters and I built them like this:

Below are the functions I coded.

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Shows a message with what the program is doing.
void ShowIntroduction(void)
{
    printf("My program finds a sum etc");
}


// find the sum of the numbers enter until 0 value
int sum(void)
{
    int s=0,n;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n > 0)
            s=s+n;
    }
    while(n != 0);


   return s;
}


// show the result
void sumResult(int a)
{
    printf("The sum is %d", a);
}

// find the result of sum/y
double result(int s,int y)
{
        double res;
        res=s/(double)(y);
        return res;
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    scanf("%d",&y);
    ShowIntroduction();
    sumResult(sum());
    result(sum(),y);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to apelate the functions in main. How to finish the program what mistakes did I make? How to correct them?

Comment: `int sum(void)` lacks a `return`.  Save time: enable all warnings.

Comment: And `sum(void);` is pointless, it calls the `sum` function, but the result is discarded. Is't like calling the sinus function like this `sin(angle);`.

Comment: Also, a call to a function without any parameters should be like `f1();` (without the `void` keyword).

Comment: This part of your question is unclear: _"Also, my program read a number "y" from keyboard and I need to find the result of the sum/y"_. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I edited the question and my code.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // <<< don't forget the herader files, they are essential!!

// Shows a message with what the program is doing.
void ShowIntroduction(void)
{
    printf("My program finds a sum etc");
}

// find the sum of the numbers enter until 0 value
int sum(void)
{
    int s=0,n;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n != 0)   //<<< n different from 0, not > 0
            s=s+n;
    }
    while(n != 0);

   return s;   // <<<< return the result here!!
}

// show the result
void sumResult(int a)
{
    printf("The sum is %d", a);
}

int main()
{
    ShowIntroduction();
    sumresult(sum());
}
```

I removed useless functions and comments and renamed the `f1` function to a more meaningful name.

I suggest you read the chapter dealing with functions in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: I tried to write the rest of the functions to finish the program.

Comment: Here is the code https://pastebin.com/MWTRQzDE .I got another problem.My program finds the sum but when it should display the result of the sum / y it asks me to give the values again for the sum until 0 value then the program closes.I think I apelate the result function in a wrong way.How to correct this?

Comment: Ask another question